# How to access services running in KVM-guest (virtual network) from remote

Tags: iptables, reverse-proxy, kvm-virtualization, port-forwarding, virtual-network

Background:
I am running an Openshift installation inside a KVM-VM and I can access the VM from the KVM-Host. I need to access Openshift from another machine. KVM is setup via virtual network using NAT.

- KVM-Host: 192.168.33.26 (eth0)
- KVM-Guest: 192.168.100.246 (virbr0 and vnet0)
- Access from: 192.168.33.50

My first idea was to use port-forwarding with iptables on the KVM-host.

```
# taken from https://aboullaite.me/kvm-qemo-forward-ports-with-iptables/

# connections from outside
iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -d  192.168.100.246 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.100.246:8443
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.100.246 --dport 8443 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.33.26

# Masquerade local subnet
iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -d  192.168.100.246 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -o virbr0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Those rules seemed to work (Openshift is answering), but the redirect to the login-page isn't affected by iptables

https://192.168.33.26:8443/console -> redirects to https://192.168.100.246:8443/oauth/authorize wheras it should be https://192.168.33.26:8443/oauth/authorize

As @week pointed out, redirects are managed at application layer and I need a reverse proxy or some routes.

Can someone provide a configuration for nginx (I've read that it can function as a reverse proxy)? Or what is another way to get access to a virtual network?

Comment: Redirects are given on application layer, by guest, which isn't configured for address 192.168.33.26. I see two ways around, you may add routes for clients accessing and guest or setup a reverse https proxy on host. In both cases there's no need for address translation.

Comment: @week Thanks for the clarification. I've updated the question

Comment: I would recommend to setup a reverse https proxy on the host. Thus you won't need to use address translation for this action.

Comment: Actually, the iptables-solution works for my case after making sure the kvm-guest can be accessed via DNS-name (see https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2017/03/03/howto-automated-dns-resolution-for-kvmlibvirt-guests-with-a-local-domain/ ). After that, I just added an entry to my remote /etc/hosts. A reverse proxy is probably the best solution, but I was not able to get to work due to a https-redirect to a login page.